# Scanning until new line

Tags: c, scanf

I want to read all the text entered until a new line character is entered.

This is my code.

```
int i=0;
char ch[MAX];
printf("Enter the text\n");
while(true)
{
     scanf("%c",&ch[i]);
     if(ch[i]=='\n')
         break;
     i++;
}
```

But when I try to execute it reads only one word.

I have also tried `scanf("%s",ch);` but the result is the same.

Comment: @almasshaikh No, `gets()` should *never* be recommended. It's dangerous.

Comment: "it reads only one word"-No. Your code does exacly what you need. Or another way would be to use `scanf("%[^\n]",ch);getchar();`

Comment: You haven't null-terminated your string.  You also don't check that `scanf()` returned a character; you should always check that it returned what you expected.  You should also be checking that the input does not exceed the length of `ch` so you don't have a buffer overflow (in this case, that would be a [stack overflow](http://stackoverflow.com), of course).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're not checking that `scanf()` succeeds before relying on `ch[i]` to have a valid value, that's not a good idea.

Just use [`fgets()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/fgets) to read a whole line at once.

Comment: Thank you
I just googled about fgets()
char *fgets(char *str, int n, FILE *stream)

What should be the argument *stream so as to read from keyboard

Comment: @AdityaKiran , In your case,you can use `fgets(ch,MAX,stdin);`

Answer (score 9):

Transferring comment to answer.

Your code will work. The code you posted scans everything until a newline character(`\n`) is found. But as [Jonathan Leffler](https://stackoverflow.com/users/15168) commented, you never NUL-terminate your string. To do it just use

```
ch[i]='\0';
```

after the loop. Also, the user could enter more characters than `MAX-1`(One extra for the `\0` at the end) and this could cause a [buffer overflow](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Buffer_overflow). You should add a check like

```
if(i==MAX-1)
break;
```

just before your `scanf` in order to prevent it from overflowing.

Note that `scanf("%s",ch);` will scan until it encounters a space or a newline character.

---

Instead of looping and scanning character by character, just use

```
scanf("%[^\n]",ch);
getchar();
```

The above `scanf` scans everything until a newline character is found and puts them in `ch`. The `getchar()` then discards the `\n` from the `stdin`. You can also improve safety by limiting the amount of characters that `scanf` reads into `ch`.

```
scanf("%49[^\n]",ch);
```

The above `scanf` will scan a maximum of 49 characters and will add a `\0` at the end. You can substitute the value of `MAX-1` there. I've used 50 as an example.

Comment: You've not null terminated the string; you've not checked for the length of the buffer.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler , Yeah.You are right. I've edited the answer.

Comment: I'm now a little concerned aboubt your comments about the macro MAX in the format string.  If you have `#define MAX 39` (for sake of argument), and macros `#define STRINGIZE(x) EVALUATE(x)` and `#define EVALUATE(x) #x`, and you define `char ch[MAX+1];`, then you could use `scanf("%" STRINGIZE(MAX) "[^\n]", ch)`, but MAX must expand to a simple number, not to a general expression.  Otherwise, I don't see how it can be made to work.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler , I just tried what I described in my answer and GCC threw a warning :/(`unknown conversion type character 'M' in format` and points at the `scanf`) . I thought that the preprocessor replaces all `MAX` in the program with 50(if we had `#define MAX 50`) before compiling the program. And I tried what you said and it worked.....

Comment: @JonathanLeffler ,Dosen't the preprocessor do its work before the compilation stage?

Comment: Yes, but the preprocessor in Standard C doesn't expand macros inside strings.  In pre-standard C, some pre-processors would look for macro arguments inside strings in the macro expansion, but that was a long time ago!  The `#` operator was introduced to handle that; the `##` operator was introduced to handle token pasting which was done with `#define PASTE(x,y) x/**/y` in some pre-standard processors.  The standard requires a space in place of the comment, and the use of `#define PASTE(x, y) x ## y` to paste arguments together.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler , Ah. That explains why my idea didn't work. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

As commented by @Jonathan Leffler, OP 's code does not  null terminate the string or prevent buffer overflow.

Since code fetches 1 `char` at a time, use the much simpler `fgetc()`.

```
int i=0;
char ch[MAX];
int single;  // Important that this in an int to distinguish EOF from input.

printf("Enter the text\n");

while((single = fgetc(stdin)) != EOF) {
  if (i >= (MAX-1)) {
    ;  // Too many, do not save or maybe indicate error
  } else {
    ch[i++] = single;
  }
  if (single == '\n') {
    break;
  }
}
ch[i] = '\0';  // Add termination
```

Answer (score 0):

your code working fine . I checked, it reads a line not a word.

Comment: The code does not null terminate the string or ensure that there is no buffer overflow.

Answer (score 0):

I hope it will be better for you with respect to your code :

```
int main()
{
    int i=0;
    char ch[100];
    printf("Enter the text\n");
    gets(ch);  // input text
    puts(ch);  // output text
    return 0;
}
```

input : `asdf ghjkl zxcvb`

output: `asdf ghjkl zxcvb`

Comment: NO!  Absolutely never, _never_, **never**, ***never*** suggest the use of `gets()`.  It is poisonously awful.  It is no longer standard C, and arguably (easily arguably) never should have been — though, that said, there were reasons for including it in C89.  See [Why is the `gets()` function dangerous? Why should it not be used?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1694036/why-is-the-gets-function-dangerous-why-should-it-not-be-used)

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Never say never. If someone wants elegant code to buffer overflow on purpose, scanf and gets are great candidates :)